# Is apache CXF 3.0.10 compatible with TLS 1.2?

Tags: apache, java-8, cxf, tls1.2

We are currently on the below mentioned version of the technologies:

Java 8,
TLS 1.1,
CXF 3.0.10,
SAML1

We want to upgrade to TLS1.2 and be sure if it is compatible with our current version of cxf as it would become tricky for us to upgrade to SAML2 (near future upgrade planned) using OpenSAML3 as it supports only newer version of Cxf.

I tried researching the internet for this but did not get anything in particular.

Can anybody tell if upgrading TLS without upgrading to newer version of cxf is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, as shown by [this CXF unit test in 3.0.10 code](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/cxf-3.0.10/systests/transports/src/test/java/org/apache/cxf/systest/https/ciphersuites/CipherSuitesTest.java#L468): `org.apache.cxf.systest.https.ciphersuites.CipherSuitesTest#testAESIncludedTLSv12()` .
This gives you an [example of XML configuration as well](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/cxf-3.0.10/systests/transports/src/test/resources/org/apache/cxf/systest/https/ciphersuites/ciphersuites-client-tlsv12.xml):

```
<http:conduit name="https://localhost:.*">
        <http:tlsClientParameters disableCNCheck="true" secureSocketProtocol="TLSv1.2">
            <sec:trustManagers>
                <sec:keyStore type="jks" password="password" resource="keys/Truststore.jks"/>
            </sec:trustManagers>
            <sec:cipherSuites>
                <sec:cipherSuite>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</sec:cipherSuite>
            </sec:cipherSuites>
        </http:tlsClientParameters>
</http:conduit>
```

And the official doc: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/tls-configuration.html

but don't take this doc as granted for CXF 3.0.10 since TLSv1.3 may not be supported by this version I guess.